# Simple javascript game, hide / show random square

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

I'm working on a simple game and I need some help to improve my code

So here's the game:

Some square show and hide randomely for a few seconds and you have to clic on them.
I use RaphaelJS to draw the square and a few of JQuery ($.each() function)

I work in a div, that's how I draw my squares (6 squares), x y are random numbers.

```
 var rec1 = paper.rect(x, y, 50, 50).attr({
            fill: "blue",});
```

**Can I use for() to build my squares with a different var name for each one ?** 
I try with var = varName+i but it didn't work.

To hide and show the square I use two functions call with two setTimeout:

```
 function box1()  {rec1.show();}
 function hidebox1()  {rec1.hide();}
 var time1 = setTimeout(box1, 1000);
 var time1 = setTimeout(hidebox1, 2000);
```

I know it looks crappy...

**I'm sure there is a way to use a toggle, or something more fancy to do that if you could help me finding it :) Because right now I have to do that for every square...**

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Why not just put the "square" objects into an array?

Comment: ok, good idea, I'll try to combine the array with my loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your instinct to try to use `varName` plus some `i` to identify which `varName` you want is spot on, and JavaScript (like most languages) has that idea built in through what's called an ***array***.

A simple one looks something like this:

```
var foo = [1, 5, 198, 309];
```

With that array, you can access `foo[0]` which is `1`, or `foo[3]` which is `309`.

Note two things: First, we identify which element of the array we want using square brackets. Second, we start counting at ***0***, not 1.

You can create an empty array like `var varName = [];` and then add new elements to it using `varName.push( newValueToPutIn );`

With those tools, you can now get at what you wanted. Now you can do something like:

```
var recs = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    var rec = paper.rect(x, y, 50, 50).attr({fill: 'blue'});
    recs.push(rec);
}
```

And `recs[0]` and `recs[1]` and so forth will refer to your various boxes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for these explanations concerning the array, I get it :)

Comment: If this is what resolved your problem, accept the answer by clicking the checkmark over on the left. Having few accepted answers will discourage people from helping in the future.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, an array is the way to go.
For the second part, you could encapsulate the square and its show/hide stuff into a new anonymous object, like this:

```
var recs = [];
var numberOfRecs = 6;
for (var i = 0; i < numberOfRecs; i++) {
    //determine x and y?
    recs.push({
        box: paper.rect(x, y, 50, 50).attr({ fill: "blue" }),
        showBriefly: function(timeFromNow, duration) {
            window.setTimeout(this.box.show, timeFromNow);
            window.setTimeout(this.box.hide, timeFromNow + duration);
        }
    });
}


//show the 3rd box 1000 ms from now, for a duration of 1000 ms
recs[2].showBriefly(1000, 1000);
```

Comment: thanks for this, first time I deal with object, looks interesting : )

Comment: Hi Mischelle, I've another question, why do you use the ":" when you set the showBriefly function ?

Comment: This is the syntax for creating an anonymous object; it's essentially JSON. {} creates the object, then within the object, you can define properties as name:value (in this case the value is a function.)